# How to see branch information?

Tags: git, terminal, command-line-interface, branch

I've multiple branches. Branch **A,B,C.....J**. I just want to know how these branch are originated? 
 For eg. I want to know  from which branch **Branch C** has been originated in **terminal**?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk

Comment: @BookOfZeus it was not what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Branches do not have "parent" branches in git.  Or equivalently, git does not keep track of what branch another branch was "created from".  (In fact, a branch doesn't have to be "created from" another branch at all.)

The only way that branches are related is: how much history they share.  You can sometimes infer a more structured understanding of a repo's branches, but generally that requires some knowledge of the team's intent.  For example, if you know that a team uses a gitflow branch strategy, then you can infer that `feature` branches are generally considered to have a single `development` branch as their parents, and that it has `master` as its parent.  But that's all just how *people* think about the branches; git doesn't know and doesn't care.

You can get a visualization of the branches with `git log --graph`, or a UI tools such as `gitk` (I use `gitk --all` quite a lot for this purpose).  But beware that in these tools, which branch is drawn "to the side" is basically arbitrary.  If you see a graph like

```
A -- B -- C <--(branch1)
      \
       D -- E <--(branch2)
```

you might infer that `branch2` was created from `branch1`; but as far as git is concerned it's just as reasonable to assume that `branch1` was created from `branch2`; all we really know is that they share a history (from `B`).

(If branches have been merged together, the merge offers some hint as to which branch might be the parent; but this is still not definitive as some strategies involve merges from a "parent" branch to a long-lived "child" branch as well as final merges from "child" branches back to the "parent".)

So... To the question you're asking, there just isn't an answer.  You may need to go back to what you're trying to accomplish by knowing this, and think of another way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

(alternative formulation of the question after clarification in comments)

> How to know which branch is the "parent" of the branch, the branch it has been created *from*?

Stated like that, the question is loaded with a misunderstanding about branches in git. A branch can be created to point at any commit, whether this commit is actually reachable from any branch. When you do the following :

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b new_branch
```

...you create a new branch, with a `<refspec>` that is not explicitly given here so assumed to be `HEAD`, resolved to `master`, itself resolved to a specific commit. So `master` and `new_branch` do **not** have any special or meaningful relationship in this situation.

Comment: You said right. I want to know > **How to know which branch is the "parent" of the branch, the branch it has been created from?**

Comment: @RajeshK.Chaudhary OK thanks for clarifying, so as I said lastly, there's not really an answer, git does not store this information as metadata for the branch, there are no branch metadata at all. But maybe you need this information X for a problem Y... ?